# Passing data between screens, route.params, React Native navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, routeparams

I'm trying to pass some data between two screens in my app. I'm using for this route.params from react-navigation
(here is the docs https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/).

In the first component - home.js - I have an array with some data and FlatList component. Home.js displays data in my app correctly.

In the second component - reviewsDetails.js- I'm trying to display data /item.title/ from
home.js but I have this error:  "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'item')".

I am looking for a solution to this problem

Here is my code:

home.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text, FlatList,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'


function Home({navigation}) {
    const [reviews, setReviews] = useState(
        [
            {title:"Zelda", rating:1, body:'lorem ipsum', key:1},
            {title:"Cruella", rating:1, body:'lorem ipsum', key:2},
            {title:"Voldemort", rating:1, body:'lorem ipsum', key:3},

        ]
    )


    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
<FlatList
data={reviews}
renderItem={({item})=>(
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> navigation.navigate("reviewDetails", item)}> 

    <Text>{item.title}</Text>
  
</TouchableOpacity>

)}

/>

        </View>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

reviewDetails.js

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, Button, StyleSheet } from "react-native";


export default function ReviewDetails({ route, navigation }) {
  const { item } = route.params;

  return (
    <View style={globalStyles.container}>
      <Text>{item.title}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

And here is the error
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5FxR.png)

Codesandbox with source code: [link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/weathered-lake-u8fcs?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

I will be grateful for any advice

EDIT.

Additional info :)

Here is also my navigation.js:

```
mport { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import React from 'react';

import about from '../screens/about'
import home from '../screens/home'
import reviewDetails from '../screens/reviewDetails'



const Tab= createBottomTabNavigator();

const AppNavigator=()=>(

    <Tab.Navigator>

        <Tab.Screen name="about" component={about}></Tab.Screen>
        <Tab.Screen name="home" component={home}></Tab.Screen>
        <Tab.Screen name="reviewDetails" component={reviewDetails}></Tab.Screen>

    </Tab.Navigator>
) 

export default AppNavigator;
```

and app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import AppNavigator from "./navigation/navigation.js"

export default function App(){

return(

  <NavigationContainer>

<AppNavigator>
  </AppNavigator>  </NavigationContainer>
)

}
```

If its helpfull - I use  version 6.0.2 of react-navigation/native and 6.0.7 of react-navigation/stack

Comment: How is ReviewDetails screen registered in the navigator? Also, I wouldn't expect the property `item` to exist on the params you are sending. Maybe you meant `navigation.navigate("reviewDetails", {item})`

Comment: @windowsill, here is how I register my reviewDetailsScreen in my navigation.js :


 
const Tab= createBottomTabNavigator();

const AppNavigator=()=>(

    <Tab.Navigator>

        <Tab.Screen name="about" component={about}></Tab.Screen>
        <Tab.Screen name="home" component={home}></Tab.Screen>
        <Tab.Screen name="reviewDetails" component={reviewDetails}></Tab.Screen>

    </Tab.Navigator>

This is how app.js looks:
<NavigationContainer>
<AppNavigator>
  </AppNavigator>  </NavigationContainer>

Comment: I was trying with this option which you suggest: navigation.navigate("reviewDetails", {item}), but still I have the same error in reviewDetails.js. If it helps, I use version 6.0.2 of react-navigation/native and 6.0.7 of react-navigation/stack

Comment: Try this syntax instead `navigate({routeName, params, action, key})`

Comment: Still the same error in reviewDetails: cannot read properties of undefined 'item'

Comment: I edited my question and I completed it with navigation.js and app.js code. I Hope, now everything is more accurate

Comment: Can you show the updated navigate call? Is it `navigate({routeName:"reviewDetails", params: {item}})`

Comment: Sure, this is the update:      <FlatList data={reviews} renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>navigation.navigate({routeName: "reviewDetails",params: { item }})}>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass params like this from `home` screen. Pass it in an object named `data` (This can be named as anything you want)

```
onPress={() => {
              navigation.navigate("reviewDetails", {
                data: item,
              });
            }}
```

And then get it on the next screen like this on `reviewDetails` screen

```
const { data } = route.params;
```

Comment: I also changes in my review details  <Text>{data.title}</Text>

now everything works well, thank you!